# SQL server row with relative value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table :

```
Name   |  money_earned
_______________________

john   |   100
paul   |   200
ringo  |   300
george |   200
```

I want to calc ( in the most **intelligent** way) - *near each row*

What is the *percentage of benefit*( of each beatle)  - *relative* to the total sum

So i want a reult like this :  ( the sum is 800)

```
Name   |  money_earned| his_Percentage
__________________________________

john   |   100        |   0.125
paul   |   200        |   0.25
ringo  |   300        |   0.375
george |   200        |   0.25
```

Thank :)

### edit

I'll be glad to have a solution like `rollup` does.

it count the sum , and overall sum...something like this function.

So lets say I want it in 1 query without declaring extra pre-calculated values.

Comment: Why do you need it in 1 statement? Is this a limitation of your data access layer? If so, can you just put your logic into a stored procedure and call it? You should make your code as readable and maintainable as possible, not as short as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Name,
       money_earned,
       money_earned / sum(money_earned) over() as his_Percentage
from [Table]
```

Comment: his_Percentage will be truncated to 0 in all rows

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - That depends on the data type for `money_earned`. Since I don't know I think it is better to provide an answer without code that tries to fix something that might not be broken.

Comment: love your solutions. Now you know why i wrote ( something `like` rollup). but people didnt understand... you did.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (This way should be the most effective from the performance perspective)

```
DECLARE @sum INT
SELECT @sum = SUM(money_earned) FROM table

SELECT Name, money_earned, CAST(money_earned as float) / @sum as his_Percentage 
FROM table
```

OR

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT SUM(money_earned) as summ FROM table
)
    SELECT Name, money_earned, CAST(money_earned as float) / summ as his_Percentage 
    FROM table
    CROSS JOIN CTE
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, money_earned, 
    CAST(money_earned as float) / (SELECT SUM(money_earned) FROM table) as his_Percentage 
FROM table
```

Comment: Andrey , believe me I could have done this myself. Thats why i wrote Intelligent way.p.s thanks for your effort :)

Comment: So, please explain what do you mean by this? What is wrong with this simple way?

Comment: I can add CTE into the query, but why? What exactly do you want?

Comment: 1 line of query which does it.

Comment: And one more update. But! The most intelligent the first one, I believe

Comment: yep . thank you. I thought there is a solution with something like rollup or something...

Comment: @AndreyGurinov but it can be in this situation

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table(name varchar(10), money_earned int)

insert @t values('john',100 ),('paul',200 ),('ringo',300 ),('george',200)

select name, money_earned, 
cast(1.0 * money_earned / sum(money_earned) over () as numeric(4,3)) his_Percentage,
cast(100.0 * money_earned / sum(money_earned) over () as numeric(4,1)) REAL_his_Percentage
from @t
```

Result:

```
name       money_earned his_Percentage                REAL_his_Percentage
---------- ------------ ----------------------------- --------------------
john       100          0.125                         12.5
paul       200          0.250                         25.0
ringo      300          0.375                         37.5
george     200          0.250                         25.0
```